# Variable's "bodyguard" in Python

Tags: python

I find myself running multiple filtering functions on a variable (`pd.DataFrame` in my case), however, when the variable reaches zero length there is no point in proceeding and I want the function to return a default value

My pseudo-code looks like:

```
def filter_function(df):
    if len(df) == 0:
        return []
    df = filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero1(df)
    if len(df) == 0:
        return []
    df = filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero2(df)
    if len(df) == 0:
        return []
    df = filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero3(df)
    if len(df) == 0:
        return []
    return df
```

I'm looking for a more programmatic way (maybe a kind of *decorator*?) to eliminate the repetitive `if`-block.

Comment: Why do your filters fail on empty input?

Comment: Put your filter_functions in a list and iterate through it?

Comment: This kind of thing is common in functional programming - a result monad is one kind of solution (I don't know if there's a good implementation of one in Python somewhere and library recommendations are off-topic here anyway).

Comment: I imagine this would work correctly without checking for empty dataset at all. And that is what I would do - not check. Your logic here is "why proceed is that is not needed?". My logic is "why test for empty dataset if that is not needed?"

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, roll the repetitive code into a loop.

```
def filter_function(df):
    for func in (
        filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero1,
        filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero2,
        filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero3
    ):
        if len(df) == 0:
            return []
        df = func(df)
    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

@triplee, I can't comment yet. your for loop misses one iteration if the third case occurs and matches the "len(df) == 0" condition.

adding a function that returns df will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function which calls another function:

```
def call_if_has_data(function, df, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(df) == 0:
        return []

    df = function(df, *args, **kwargs)

    if len(df) == 0:
        return []

    return df
```

You could omit `args` and `kwargs` if your filtering functions have no arguments.

To use it:

```
def filter_function(df):
    df = call_if_has_data(filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero1, df)
    df = call_if_has_data(filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero2, df)
    df = call_if_has_data(filter_function_taht_will_fail_if_len_df_is_zero3, df)
    return df
```

There is a bit of confusion about data types though — the type of the result is either a `DataFrame` or a `list`. If I wrote this code, I'd use an empty `DataFrame` instead on an empty `list`. But you could do whatever you want; just be aware of this distinction of data types.